# Errors trying to use AdWhirl with Admob

Tags: ios, ios5, admob, adwhirl

I am trying to setup a test application for AdWhirl to see how this functions etc. I have setup a new application in Xcode which just loads a single view.

I have downloaded and added the latest SDK for AdWhirl then removed all the folders in adapters I am not using...Per step 4 - https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/ios/AdWhirliOSSDKSetup.html

I have then downloaded the SDK for AdMob and setup a new application on Admob, entering the relevant pub ID into the settings for AdWhirl... still with me?

Without making any further changes to the app itself I am getting build errors below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
"_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
  -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have all the relevant libraries included picture to show. Also included a pic to show the layout of files.

Has anyone had this issue and can help. A lot of the posts on here say to check MessageUI framework and check build settings for framework search paths but this is all fine in this case...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the **StoreKit** framework, which is needed by Admob. Try adding it to your project. See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Comment: Thank you! I looked at this soo many times I guess my eyes decided not to work

Comment: I added this framework as optional, since it was for 6.0.1+ like the AdSupport framework which was also needed. I take it this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed *StoreKite.framework* was automatically unlinked when I toggled the "In-App Purchase" switch to OFF in *Capabilities* tab of my project. Cheeky.